# Is it legitimate to pass an argument as void*?

Tags: c, pthreads, void

I have just started learning pthreads API and I am following the tutorial [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Abstract)

However, in an example program of `pthread_create`, the sample program creates a long variable and **passes its value**, typecasted as `void*`. In the thread entry function, it dereferences it just like a long.

Is this legit?
I understand if I pass the address of variable `t`, every thread would be acting on the same variable and not on a copy of it. Can we do this because it's a `void*` and the compiler has no idea about what type we are sending?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: So your question is about validity of cast or validity of passing pointer as 4th argument for pthread_create()?

Comment: @qrdl: actually its both but i was more interested in passing long as 4th argument for pthread_create making complier think you are actually sending an address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as long as `sizeof(long) <= sizeof(void*)`, and that every value of `long` can be represented as a `void*`.

Better would be to pass the address of the variable. You can cast from a `T*` to `void*`, and back again safely and without assumption.

Comment: @Charles `sizeof(void)` and `sizeof(void*)` are different beasts

Answer (score 4):

It's as legitimate as any kind of typecasting.  The point is that nothing can be done with the value the argument points to, until it is typecast, hence `tid = (long)threadid`.

Check the older Q&A [When to use a void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025579/when-to-use-a-void-pointer).

Comment: You're saying, `void*` means "pointer to something", but that "something" needs to be defined before it can be used, right?

Comment: @Abel: right.  The point is when you want to do something with a pointer that can't be given the type information.