# cpp Is there a reason to prefer vector<class_type*> to vector<void*>?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have class `A_class`, and I need a vector of pointers to objects of this class. Is there a good reason to prefer either of the usages:

```
vector<void*> my_vector;
vector<A_class*> my_vector;
```

is there really a difference?

Edit:
Let me rephrase - is there a difference in the way the actual array is stored? I'm not asking about safety, but about performance.

Comment: You mean besides allowing the compiler to do its work (type checking)?

Comment: `vector<*void>` doesn't make sense. Did you mean `vector<void*>`?

Comment: Besides the fact that it's faster and safer to use a class pointer? no, none at all

Comment: "cpp Is there a reason to prefer `vector<class_type *>` to `vector<void *>`?" - sure, safety.

Comment: I suggest you read a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This will explain the C++ type system and why `vector<A_class*>` is the way to do it.

Comment: @H2CO3 neither compiles, so they are both perfectly safe :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Awww :P Yeah, fixed. I shouldn't have copy-pasted.

Answer (score 4):

Using `void *` should be avoided whenever possible.

This is for two reasons:

1. You lose the type of the object.
2. The code gets messier, because you have to cast the `void *` back to the original type.

There are very few cases in C++ (thanks to templates) where `void *` is actually meaningful. I'm sure there are some, but I can't really think of any case right now (aside from when you need to use it for historical/compatibility reasons, e.g. transferring a pointer to a class to "C" code, where it doesn't understand the concept of `class`, so you can't give it the correct type).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a whole lot with `void*` unless you cast it, so there's really no advantage to using it over the actual type.

Even if the only reason was to avoid the unnecessary cast, that would be enough. It's not though. You can potentially cast the `void*` to anything and use the result incorrectly. Using the real class itself also has the added benefit that the code is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

> is there really a difference?

A `vector<void*>` would also accept values of type `int*`, `YourClassHere**` and any other pointer you can imagine. It's unsafe, so unless you have a very good reason to use it (and I can't think of many) - don't.

Why did you even consider it as an alternative?

It would also require that you explicitly cast the pointers back to `A_class*` whenever you use them (which is ugly, verbose and error prone).

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that a void pointer cannot be dereferenced directly. You will ultimately have to typecast it to your class.

So if there is not any good reason to go for a void pointer and you are sure that the vector shall store pointers to objects of A_class, then I would prefer to avoid the use of void pointers.

Comment: A good reason for a void pointer is exactly what you describe: you don't want to (be able to) dereference it. This is common when you get passed some 'user data' pointer which you eventually pass back to the pointer. You want to treat it like an opaque token.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: But you can also do this by only forward declaring the struct/class that it refers to, avoiding that someone passes some random pointer to your function by mistake. In other words `class filehandle; filehandle* fileopen(const std::string &filename); void close(filehandle *);`

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I was thinking of a case where you get passed a user-data pointer and you have no idea what it points to and you don't *want to* know what it points to. Think of the 'void*' argument to thread creation functions. You just get passed some pointer and you're supposed to hand it back to the client later.

Comment: The `void *` in thread contexts is a throwback to C days, when it was the only way to pass an arbitrary argument. In C++, you can do that with templates.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Your arguments make sense in a `C` setting, but not in `C++`. Opaque handles to objects unknown to the user are not a sensible design in `C++`. Instead you hide the design details in the class implementation, but have the interface completely transparent.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Using templates exposes information such as whether some object is copyable or constructible or the like. You can use type traits and similiar to identify all kinds of characteristics of the type. With `void*` this is not possible.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: So, make it a forward declared pointer to a class. You can't use that for anything other than identify that the type is correct. Like I said in the first comment. There is no real need to use `void *` in C++.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: But you don't *care* about the type. you don't do anything with the pointer other than storing it and lateron passing it back to the caller. There is no benefit in giving a name to the type (i.e. by having a pointer to a forward-declared struct or class).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Yes there is. You can identify incorrect pointer type - a `void *` is compatible with ANYTHING, so the code can pass some arbitrary pointer of any kind, without objection from the compiler. Sure, in most cases, this will probably quite soon reveal itself when the code is used, but I have seen cases where the "wrong" pointer is passed, and things go wrong only in very special cases.

Answer (score 0):

You chose

```
vector<*void> my_vector;
```

if you don't know objects of what type will be stored in `my_vector`. If you know they will be of type `A_class` then use

```
vector<A_class*> my_vector;
```

[using void pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025579/when-to-use-a-void-pointer)