# void * typed function parameter

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a function, `void *Client(void *threaData){}`

Can you tell me some things about `void *threadData` parameter. When you use `void *` parameter and why?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`void *` is a generic pointer which can point to any object type. The above function can take a pointer to any type and can return a pointer to any type.

A generic pointer can be used if it is not sure about the data type of data inputted by the user.

Example: The following function will print any data type provided the user input about the type of data

```
void funct(void *a, int z)
{
    if(z==1)
        printf("%d",*(int*)a); // If user inputs 1, then it means the data is an integer and type  casting is done accordingly.
    else if(z==2)
        printf("%c",*(char*)a); // Typecasting for character pointer.
    else if(z==3)
        printf("%f",*(float*)a); // Typecasting for float pointer
}
```

Comment: Quick and easy, very nice answer, maybe you could add an example where it gets used in C programming

Comment: A `void *` cannot only point to any pointer type, but in fact to any object type. But the function cannot take a pointer to any type, only void pointers and pointers to object types (but not function pointers).

Comment: @TifuiGabriel; See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1025692/2455888) too.

Comment: Thank you, your answer help me to understand this practice :).

Comment: I am learning C and i have trouble putting things together. I get an error when I use it like this for int: `int s = 3; funct(s, 1);` But it works when I pass parameter as reference  `int s = 3; funct(&s, 1);` Why?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you want to pass an integer to the `void *Client(void *threadData){}` function, so you would

```
int integer;

integer = SOME_VALUE;

Client(&integer);
```

and in the function

```
void *Client(void *threadData)
{
    int value;

    value = *(int *)threadData;
}
```

and since `void *` can be converted to any pointer type, you can pass any data you need to the `Client()` function.

Comment: And you could pass any other type to the function in the same general way — by passing a pointer to the structure containing the data.

Comment: Good question (which was 'does passing the data via a `void *` lead to violation of strict aliassing rules?'). I had to think before answering. I believe the answer is "No". Suppose the thread function is `void *thread_func(void *pdata) { … }`. Suppose you pass a pointer to `struct SomeThing` to the function as a `void *`; inside the thread function, the first thing you do is `SomeThing *args = pdata;` (or `SomeThing arg = *(SomeThing *)pdata;`) so that you only ever access the data through a pointer to the correct type, not via an aliassed type, and there's no strict aliassing issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, now i wont worry again, since what you say makes a lot of sense. Yeah, sorry for deleting the comment, I thought you was not going to answer.